# Creating and committing a tag using libgit2

Tags: c, git, libgit2

I've been working with libgit2 a little bit here and there trying to get a better understanding of how Git functions. To that end, I've been implementing a little mini-client as a learning exercise, and it's going pretty well.

However, I can't seem to figure out how to commit a tag that I have created using the `git_tag_create` function. I think I need to add it to the index, but I can't figure out how to do that either. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tags are not committed.  Tags are separate objects that point at commits, similar to how you don't have to "commit a branch," it just exists once you create it.

At the moment that a tag is created you are done, and you can push its definition to a remote repository.

Comment: That would explain why I was having such an issue with this. I guess I still have a lot to learn! Thanks.